# Why an element disappears with "overflow: visible" but is visible with "overflow: hidden"?

Tags: html, css

When I use the default `overflow` value, an `<ul>` element disappears. Here's a snipped I've tested with Google Chrome:

```css
ul {
  list-style-type: none;
  background-color: #333333;
}

li {
  float: left;
  color: white;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li>Test</li>
</ul>
```

However, when I add `overflow: hidden;` to `<ul>`, it becomes visible:

```css
ul {
  list-style-type: none;
  background-color: #333333;
  overflow: hidden;
}

li {
  float: left;
  color: white;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li>Test</li>
</ul>
```

As far as I know, the `overflow` property specifies if the overflow renders outside the element's box. Why the whole element is invisible when the default `overflow: visible` is set?

Comment: You shouldn't really use floats for positioning, there are much better ways to do this now - eg flexbox

Answer (score 1):

because your `ul` doesn't have a set `height`

> In order for overflow to have an effect, the block-level container
>   must have either a set height (height or max-height) or white-space
>   set to nowrap.

from https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/overflow